# Are these beets still edible?

Tags: food-safety, beets

I boiled some beets last weekend but then had to travel unexpectedly.  They have been in the fridge in a container.  They have some light purple watery droplets on them now.  Are they still edible? Here is a photo:

[image]

Comment: How long have these beets actually been in the fridge? 5 or 7 days?

Comment: It wouldn't let me post a pic due to I'm a newbie.  They have been in for about 7 days.

Comment: As I'm no expert and don't know what the (various) health organizations say about it, I'm not going to answer... But if it smells like beet, I'd taste it, and if it tastes like beet, I'd eat it. I wouldn't serve it to children or elderly people, just for safety. You could wash it with water before anything else.

Comment: I can understand why you are asking, that picture is kind of making me sick to my stomach to look at.

Answer (score 6):

It's a vegetable. When you cooked it you damaged the cell walls and the juice is leaking out.

I think this picture only seems unusual because of the beets' color. If these were carrots there wouldn't be a question because, of course, the juice would be less startling.

If these beets haven't started to mold or ferment- and you'd know it from the smell- then they are fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've eaten beats that had a similar appearance with no ill effects.  Let your nose tell you, as BaffledCook mentions, "if it smells like a beet", eat it.